# GATE manual annotation : more features for one type

Tags: xml, gate

I'm doing a manual annotation of a corpus in GATE. So I have created my annotation schema in xml:

```
<element name="extragraphique">
    <complexType>
      <attribute name="kind" use="optional" value="other" >
        <simpleType>
          <restriction base="string">
            <enumeration value="confusion_voyelle"/>
            <enumeration value="confusion_consonne"/>
          </restriction>
        </simpleType>   
      </attribute>
    </complexType>
  </element>
</schema>
```

The result annotations look like this:

> [image: Gate annotation]

But I would like to annotate more features (values) for one annotation type (element). Is this possible? Declaring one more value is not an option because GATE will only let me choose one feature value:

> [image: Annotation tool]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add a second attribute to the schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema">  
  <element name="extragraphique">
    <complexType>
      <attribute name="kind" use="optional" value="other" >
        <simpleType>
          <restriction base="string">
            <enumeration value="confusion_voyelle"/>
            <enumeration value="confusion_consonne"/>
          </restriction>
        </simpleType>   
      </attribute>
      <attribute name="confidence" use="optional" value="other" >
        <simpleType>
          <restriction base="string">
            <enumeration value="low"/>
            <enumeration value="high"/>
          </restriction>
        </simpleType> 
      </attribute>
    </complexType>
  </element>
</schema>
```

Screenshot form GATE:

[image: GATE screenshot]

Additional info from the GATE docs:

- [Annotation Schemas](https://gate.ac.uk/userguide/sec:corpora:schemas)
- [Schema-Driven Editing](https://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch3.html#sec:developer:schemaannotationeditor)